# Add custom button group to Home ribbon in outlook - VSTO project

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, outlook-addin

I am brand new to VSTO development.I am using visual studio 2017 community edition.I need to show two buttons as a group in the Home ribbon of outlook.I tried with Ribbon control but it shows as a new tab.I want to show the buttons as a group in the Home ribbon itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controls displayed in the new tab because you specified your own `id` of the tab. To display your group inside existing tab you need to specify `id` of this tab. `id` attribute in this case called `idMso`. For main explorer tab the `idMso` is `TabHome`. Your `ribbon.xml` may look like ...

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabHome">
        <group id="SampleGroup" label="Sample Group">
          <button id="Button" label="Sample Button" size="large" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

If you still puzzle yourself, the great way to start for customization of [Office Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is to read 3 parts of [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202.aspx).

Comment: @Sobinscott Oh, man. There are plenty of examples on [how to create your first VSTO add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx), ether from Microsoft sources or elsewhere (See the function `ThisAddIn_Startup`). Simple google search will provide you with great load of results, for example: [Global Address Book for Outlook using C# with VSTO](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1109714/webcontrols/WebControls/) You may find here even sample project. Please take a time and make your home work first, after ask specific question.